# Ranking sum of data by two categories

Tags: stata

I have data that I would like to rank by two separate categories, State and ServiceType. Essentially, there are multiple years of data for each ServiceType across various states, and I was hoping to get the sum of all years for each ServiceType **by** State, meaning each State is treated independently and the sums of the various categories are ranked only within that state, not nationally.

I've tried

```
bys State ServiceCategory (quant_variable): ///
egen rank_quant_variable= rank(sum(quant_variable)), field
```

as well as a version of above where I used a pre-calculated sum variable. Both don't really work.

Answer (score 1):

This lacks a reproducible example, as you do not give your data or phrase your problem in terms of a dataset we could download, for example as loaded with or referred to in Stata. There is no need to give the full dataset but just a minimal example with the same structure.

The call to `sum()` here would be to Stata's `sum()` function, which yields the cumulative or running sum, which evidently isn't what you want. So that case is easy to dismiss.

The problem remaining is quite what you did in the code you don't show with a pre-calculated sum.

At a guess you worked out

```
bys State ServiceCategory: egen sum = total(quant_variable)
```

and then pushed that `sum` through `rank()`. But that would use each value of `sum` as many times as it occurred.

Perhaps you want something more like this:

```
egen tag = tag(State ServiceCategory) 
bysort State: egen rank_quant_variable = rank(sum) if tag, field 
bysort State (rank): replace rank = rank[1]
```

But it's really hard (for me) to visualize this without details on what you did or an example to work on.